# BLAS/LAPACK installation

Tags: r, bash, cygwin, gnu

I tried to install some R packages in R within Cygwin. But the installation failed with error message below:

```
    g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -o BayesTree.dll BirthDeath.o ChangeRule.o Funs.o Lib.o Likelihood.o List.o MuS.o Node.o Prior.o Rlob.o Swap.o mbart.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR -lintl -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -ltirpc -lrt -ldl -lm -liconv -licuuc -licui18n
   mbart.o: In function `mbart':
    /tmp/RtmpFTd5dY/R.INSTALL299c3c70eccb/BayesTree/src/mbart.cpp:336: undefined reference to `dcopy_'
    /tmp/RtmpFTd5dY/R.INSTALL299c3c70eccb/BayesTree/src/mbart.cpp:337: undefined reference to `daxpy_'
    /tmp/RtmpFTd5dY/R.INSTALL299c3c70eccb/BayesTree/src/mbart.cpp:338: undefined reference to `daxpy_'
    /tmp/RtmpFTd5dY/R.INSTALL299c3c70eccb/BayesTree/src/mbart.cpp:347: undefined reference to `daxpy_'
    /tmp/RtmpFTd5dY/R.INSTALL299c3c70eccb/BayesTree/src/mbart.cpp:348: undefined reference to `daxpy_'
    /tmp/RtmpFTd5dY/R.INSTALL299c3c70eccb/BayesTree/src/mbart.cpp:350: undefined reference to `dcopy_'
    /tmp/RtmpFTd5dY/R.INSTALL299c3c70eccb/BayesTree/src/mbart.cpp:384: undefined reference to `ddot_'
    /tmp/RtmpFTd5dY/R.INSTALL299c3c70eccb/BayesTree/src/mbart.cpp:357: undefined reference to `dcopy_'
    /tmp/RtmpFTd5dY/R.INSTALL299c3c70eccb/BayesTree/src/mbart.cpp:358: undefined reference to `daxpy_'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [/usr/lib/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: BayesTree.dll] Error 1
    ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘BayesTree’
    * removing ‘/usr/lib/R/site-library/BayesTree’
```

I looked up the error, most of the posts I looked into suggest adding BLAS library or LAPACK library. But I already have installed both in Cygwin:

```
/usr/lib/libblas.a
/usr/lib/libblas.dll.a
/usr/lib/liblapack.a
/usr/lib/liblapack.dll.a
```

So I don't really know what the problem is.

Comment: I don't know the answer since I'm on a NIX box, but I have read many times in Rhelp (the original place to ask R questions) that running R in Cygwin is not supported by R-Core. You might want to search their archives or one of the mirrors.

Comment: @42 Is not supported by R-Core but it is available as cygwin package.

Comment: @GorillaInR The link command is is missing the `-lblas -llapack`. May be the package you are building is expecting an integrated lapack as preferred in the past by R.